# Visualize call stack of method calls in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I wonder if there is a way to visually represent a call stack of a method.

Meaning for example:

- ServiceAdapter.GetMessage

  - calls Manager.GetMessage

    - calls Agent.GetMessage

      - calls Repo.GetMessageById
    - calls Agent.GetUserById

      - calls Repo.GetUserById
    - calls Agent.GetRating

      - call Repo.GetRatingForMessage
  - ..

This way it would by very easy to navigate through a piece of code and visualize its dependencies.

Is there an existing extension for this in Visual Studio?

Comment: something of this sort?

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kirillosenkov/archive/2009/01/10/call-hierarchy-navigation-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx

Comment: yup, that's it, if you provide it as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for the Call Hierarchy window.
Select a method, then press Ctrl + K, T.

Answer (score 1):

On the method name, left click with your mouse and click Call Hierarchy.